# How to geocode the polygon of a street, instead of just a point

Tags: python, geopandas, geocoding, geopy

I want to geocode many street addresses using GeoPy/GeoPandas, but the results of my queries only return points. Is it possible to obtain the entire polygon of a street, i.e., when it begins and ends?

**Edit:**

For a more concrete example of what I am doing, see this related question: [GeoPandas reading coordinates in inverse order](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/431242/199434)

Comment: It's certainly possible, but only by looking up the polygon in a data store of some kind (and only by compiling that data in the first place). What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried using the Google API for Geocoding. As far as I understand, it only gives you a single data point for a street address. I was hoping for references of where I could look for more detailed data on these streets.

Answer (score 2):

Google Geocoder doesn't seem to support returning precise polygons. But it does return an approximate bounding box (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#results):

```
>>> import geopy
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3("...")
>>> location = geolocator.geocode("new york")
>>> location
Location(New York, NY, USA, (40.7127753, -74.0059728, 0.0))
>>> location.raw["geometry"]
{'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.9175771, 'lng': -73.70027209999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 40.4773991, 'lng': -74.25908989999999}}, 'location': {'lat': 40.7127753, 'lng': -74.0059728}, 'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.9175771, 'lng': -73.70027209999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 40.4773991, 'lng': -74.25908989999999}}}
```

However, Nominatim-based geocoders do indeed support returning precise polygons (see https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode):

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
>>> location = geolocator.geocode("new york", geometry='wkt')
>>> location
Location(New York, United States, (40.7127281, -74.0060152, 0.0))
>>> location.raw["geotext"]
'MULTIPOLYGON(((-74.25909 40.497207,-74.259028 40.497107,<STRIPPED>,-74.0407472 40.7001669)))'
```

Comment: I will try this. I have used Nominatim in the past, but a significant part of the results was wrong (that's why I switched to the Google API, which returned results with better quality). My data is very imprecise, so I guess Google is better at figuring out what it actually means. The Google bounding boxes are defined by northeast and southwest limits, is that it?